# Canvas: using moveTo + lineTo for the same position

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

Prior to one of the recent updates, Chrome rendered this code as a filled circle:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 20); // same pos
ctx.stroke();
```

I found this behavior useful for a drawing service because I didn't have to manually process the case when the user just wanted to put a single dot.

Now, this code draws nothing. Is this behavior somehow defined in the specs? Should I consider this as a bug, or I have to process this case differently from now on?

Comment: You always should have processed this case differently, unfortunately...